# How can I pass a complex object from controller to the view (jsp)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to pass a complex object from Spring MVC controller to the view and be able to use all of it's properties. The object has the list of other class's objects in itself, and those have lists of other class's objects and so on. I'm trying to render multilevel unordered list out of it that will be used as treeView.

Can I do this, and how?

I've already tried passing it "regularly" btw, but I get

```
org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp(29,8) '${rootAsObject.JWSs}' Property 'JWSs' not found on type com.model.Root
```

My controller...

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String someFunction(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {

    model.addAttribute("rootAsAttribute", this.GenerateTreeView(appconfigProperties));
    model.addObject("rootAsObject", this.GenerateTreeView(appconfigProperties));

    return "index"; 
}
```

My index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div style="float: left; width: 20%; height: 100%; overflow-x: scroll">
    <ul>
        <c:forEach items="${rootAsObject.JWSs}" var="jws">
            <li>${jws.ActualFile.getName()}</li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 80%" id="thePage">
    <iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" runat="server" style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
            frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You pass a complex object the same way as you pass a simple one: by storing it in the model.

Comment: I think I've tried that. I just edited my question...

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is: the object, of type com.model.Root, is found by the JSP. But it doesn't have a property named 'JWSs'. So the problem is in com.model.Root or in the JSP. Not in your controller. First ruleof programming: read the error message.

Comment: No, no, Root has JWSs property 100%, I use this model in other project related to this one, and even in this one if I generate treeview directly from the Root object, JWSs are there. I want to avoid generating the view in the model, that's why I'm trying to render the list in .jsp

Comment: If the JSP tells you that it doesn't have a JWSs property, then it doesn't have one. Show us the code of Model. Properties, BTW, start by a lowercase character. So no, it doesn't have a JWSs property.

Answer (score 2):

You could add attribute to the model when returning the view from the controller and use JSTL expression to access the objects referenced by this attribute.

Comment: Tried, but I'm getting an exception message. Please see the edited question.

Comment: If you are trying access the property of the object make sure you have this property in the bean and the bean is a valid java bean.

Comment: I'm sorry for this next question, but "how do I do that"? I'm 100% new to Spring MVC and quite new to Java... Do you have some useful link or something?

Comment: Thanks, I'll browse it and look for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass a complex view model to your controller is by using a custom model binder. When data gets sent from your view to your controller, MVC default model binder is used to figure how to bind the values of your data to the view model. By creating a custom model binder, you get to control how the values get binded to your view model.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your object passed into view should be valid Java Bean object. 
    So all fields are private with getters and setters

Examle:

```
public class Xxx implements Serializable {
   @Getter @Setter
   private String someField;
   // constructor, etc.
}
```

2. You pass it in controller to view via :

   model.addAttribute("someName", yourJavaComplexBeanObject );
3. You use it in view via its attribute name (someName) AND properties names, 
   example:

```html
<p>${someName.someProperty}</p>
```

So you need to keep Java Bean naming conventions, field start with lowercase and has getter / setter, then you use it via field name